# 404 after refresh Vercel+React+Node+Express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, http-status-code-404, vercel

It should work, but it doesn't, and I can't figure out what the problem is. I can go to the page of my application and navigate through the pages, everything works as it should, but I can't reload the page because I get a 404. I know its easy but I'm confused.

vercel.json

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/"
    }
  ]
}
```

AppRouter

```
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
        <Route path="/notes" element={<NotesPage />} />
      </Route>
      <Route element={<Outlet />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path="/registration" element={<RegistrationPage />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
```

routes

```js
app.use(express.static("client/dist"));
app.use("/api", router);
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "dist", "index.html"));
});
```